# Pyspark error in oozie workflow

Tags: python, apache-spark, cloudera, oozie, hue

I only have access to a HUE (3.7.0) interface and through this I’m trying to run a oozie workflow which contains only a Spark action to execute a python script as you can see in this picture:

[my simple oozie workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMY34.png)

The consoli.py file is under the workspace “/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-1470040761.25/lib »
Unfortunately, I have this issue (that I don’t have if I try it with a jar file instead of a python script …) :

> Invoking Spark class now >>>
>
> python: can't open file >'/opt/yarn/nm/usercache/moet/appcache/application_1460044135313_0530/container_1>460044135313_0530_01_000001/lib/consoli.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>    Intercepting System.exit(2)

I tried to modify the workflow.xml to add a `<file>` tag in order to force the path:
    `<file>/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-1470040761.25/lib/console.py </file>`
But when I load this new workflow.xml, Oozie always add those lines in the file:

`<global>
     <job-xml>workflow.xml</job-xml>
</global>`

And the job never ends…
The initial workflow.xml (the one generated by oozie) is:

`<workflow-app name="Consolidation" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="spark-839a"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>L&#39;action a échoué, message d&#39;erreur[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="spark-839a">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name></name>
                    <value></value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name></name>
                    <value></value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <master>local[*]</master>
            <mode>client</mode>
            <name>MySpark</name>
              <class>main</class>
            <jar>lib/consoli.py</jar>
        </spark>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>`

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try the *absolute* HDFS path of your Python file in the `<jar>` element? E.g. `<jar>hdfs:///user/toto/biloute/console.py</jar>`

Comment: BTW, is the script named "consol**e**" or "consol**i**"?!?!? Because your issue could be a simple typo.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If so, how? I have a similar problem.

Comment: @KimMoritz , I run PySpark via a shell action on a shell script which calls a python file with the PySpark stuff. I had a similar error as above. I managed to fix it by adding python file as an ``<archive>`` element: ``<archive>hdfs:/path/to/file.py</archive>``. hth